# Popen.communicate() throws OSError: "[Errno 10] No child processes"

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to start up a child process and get its output on Linux from Python using the subprocess module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l', '/etc'],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

However, I experience some flakiness: sometimes, p.communicate() would throw

```
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

What can cause this exception?  Is there any non-determinism or race condition here that can cause flakiness?

Comment: What version of python are you using? It works fine for me if i take out 'extra_args'

Answer (score 7):

Are you intercepting SIGCHLD in the script? If you are then Popen will not run as expected since it relies on it's own handler for that signal.

You can check for SIGCHLD handlers by commenting out the Popen call and then running:

```
strace python <your_script.py> | grep SIGCHLD
```

if you see something similar to:

```
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, ...)
```

then, you are in trouble. You need to disable the handler prior to calling Popen and then resetting it after communicate is done (this might introduce a race conditions so beware).

```
signal.signal(SIGCHLD, handler)
...
signal.signal(SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_DFL)
'''
now you can go wild with Popen. 
WARNING!!! during this time no signals will be delivered to handler
'''
...
signal.signal(SIGCHLD, handler)
```

There is a python bug reported on this and as far as I see it hasn't been resolved yet:

http://bugs.python.org/issue9127

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi http://bugs.python.org/issue9127 visited the link but couldn't figure out in which python release the issue is fixed. Can you help me with the same.

Comment: Here's a list of releases that solves these issues http://bugs.python.org/issue1731717#msg260457

Comment: The message and the link shared above doesn't seem to be correct , since as per the versions in which the bug is filed Python 3.1, Python 3.2, Python 2.7, Python 2.6 these Python versions are mentioned in which the bug was found.

Answer (score 3):

You might be running into the bug mentioned here: http://bugs.python.org/issue1731717

Comment: If it is this bug consider updating your python to 2.5/2.6. It has been resolved.

Comment: As of 2010-09-29 the bug is still marked as "open/needs patch" and affects version 3.2, 3.1, 2.7, 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this on my Python (2.4.6-1ubuntu3). How are you running your script? How often does this occur?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem using Python 2.6.4 which I built into my home directory (because I don't want to upgrade the "built-in" Python on the machine).

I worked around it by replacing `subprocess.Popen()` with (the deprecated) `os.popen3()`.