# how can i receive a signal when a Popen terminates?

Tags: python, shell, signals, popen, terminate

in python, i have a spawned shell process which i might stop manually , or it might terminate itself when it feels like it.  can i receive a notification that it has completed, without polling it all the time?

```
class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.running = False

  def start(self):
    import os
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    self.proc = Popen(['foo'], stdout=PIPE, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
    self.running = True

  def stop(self):
    if not self.running:
      print 'already stopped'
    else:
      import os, signal
      os.killpg(self.proc.pid, signal.SIGINT)
      self.on_complete()

  def on_complete(self):
    self.running = False
```

the construct is more or less like the above.  my problem is that if the process was terminated normally, not by my own interrupt , then `self.running` remains `True` so i can not rely on that attribute for other logic in the class.

is there a simple way to have `on_complete` called for the case of normal termination, or is this a silly design in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to install a handler for `SIGCHLD`.  Read the documentation carefully, though; by registering interest in that signal, you are committing to handling child processes in the signal handler; anything that `wait`s on the subprocess itself will block until all running children have been processes by the signal handler and then error out.  This includes `system()` and `Popen`'s own subprocess cleanup.  (See [Popen.communicate() throws OSError: "[Errno 10] No child processes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008858/popen-communicate-throws-oserror-errno-10-no-child-processes), for example.)