# Gunicorn + Subprocesses raises exception [Errno 10]

Tags: python, subprocess, flask, python-2.6, gunicorn

I've stumbled across a weird exception I haven't been able to resolve... can anyone suggest what is wrong or a new design?  I'm running a Gunicorn/Flask application.  In the configuration file, I specify some work to do with an `on_starting` hook [1].  Inside that hook code, I have some code like this (nothing fancy):

```
# Called before the server is started
my_thread = package.MyThread()
my_thread.start()
```

The package.MyThread class looks like the following.  The `ls` command is unimportant, it can be any command.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
  """
    Run a command every 60 seconds.

  """
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.event = threading.Event()

  def run(self):
    while not self.event.is_set():
      ptest = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      ptest.communicate()
      self.event.wait(60)

  def stop(self):
    self.event.set()
```

Upon starting up the server, I'm always presented with this exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "__init__.py", line 195, in run
    ptest.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 721, in communicate
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1288, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 462, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

Can anyone suggest what is going on here?  I haven't tried implementing the changes in [2], they seemed hacky.

[1] - http://gunicorn.org/configure.html#server-hooks

[2] - [Popen.communicate() throws OSError: "[Errno 10] No child processes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008858/popen-communicate-throws-oserror-errno-10-no-child-processes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error turns out to be related to signal handling of `SIGCHLD`.

The `gunicorn` arbiter intercepts `SIGCHLD`, which breaks `subprocess.Popen`.  The `subprocess.Popen` module requires that `SIGCHLD` not be intercepted (at least, this is true for Python 2.6 and earlier).

According to [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue9127) this bug has been fixed in Python 2.7.

Comment: Note that newer versions on gunicorn work around this (presumably they no longer intercept `SIGCHLD`). In my testing, moving to gunicorn 0.14.x was sufficient even for Python 2.6.