# freeswitch python scripts errno 10 no child processes

Tags: python, django, django-models, freeswitch, djcelery

I' ve got an issue when running freeswitch with some python scripts inside dialplan using django.db models. Whenever it starts it causes errors:

```
freeswitch@ubuntu> 2013-08-15 06:56:08.094348 [ERR] mod_python.c:231 Error importing module
2013-08-15 06:56:08.094348 [ERR] mod_python.c:164 Python Error by calling script   "fs_scripts.ringback": <type 'exceptions.IOError'>
Message: [Errno 10] No child processes
Exception: None

Traceback (most recent call last)
File: "/home/piotrek/lettel/fs_scripts/ringback.py", line 19, in <module>
File: "/home/piotrek/lettel/api/call.py", line 3, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
File: "/home/piotrek/lettel/lettel/settings.py", line 13, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__compat__.py", line 135, in __getattr__
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/_state.py", line 19, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 10, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/abstract.py", line 12, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 24, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/log.py", line 8, in <module>
File: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/utils/compat.py", line 68, in <module>
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1337, in system
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1304, in uname
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1039, in _syscmd_uname
```

edit: the line that causes errors is a simple import from django.db:
    from django.db import models

This whole setup is already running on some server that I dont have access to, so it seems to be nothing wrong with django app or scripts...

Any help would be appreciated cause I am running out of ideas how to solve this problem...

Comment: Probably your problem is not with freeswitch but python. It would help if you can publish yout code fragment. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008858/popen-communicate-throws-oserror-errno-10-no-child-processes

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your performance and scalability requirements, despite that a softswitch have realtime requirements to run rtp stream and signalling. So is not a good solution run django applications under mod_python. Furthermore that is not the same as python interpreter directly, somethings does not work. You can check the mod_python issues here:
[mod_python issues](http://jira.freeswitch.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22mod_python%22)

I would advice you to split your python solution in a client/server architecture. The script running under mod_python will make queries to your Django application. That way you will get rid of the complexity in Freeswitch side, get scalable, improve performance and most probably get everything working OK.