# subprocess.call error: no child processes, when ran in thread

Tags: python

If I run the below code it works fine.

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/konf",
                 "-s", "/var/run/konfd.socket",
                 "--",
                 "-r", "" + oldvalue + "",
                 "-l", "" + newvalue + "",
                 "-s", sp,
                 "-p", priority])
```

However when running the code through a threaded daemon, I get this error:

```
(<type 'exceptions.OSError'>, OSError(10, 'No child processes'), <traceback obje
ct at 0x3e39b8>)
```

The code completes as expected(as in the code does what it was meant to do) but I still see this exception, any idea why?

EDIT: I should also note that it happens intermittently, not every time.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008858/popen-communicate-throws-oserror-errno-10-no-child-processes

Comment: @hyades Thanks but unfortunately I already tried the top answers on that (first isn't applicable and second is fixed in 2.7). I can try the third answer of using a deprecated method but then that doesn't seem like good or reasonable practice.